# Tinymce + Filemanager = image show browse button missing

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to have implemented filemanager + tinymce editor on my webpage. Problem is that it is not working as on the preview on tinymce site.

Tinymce working great, i downloaded filemanager on this website for tinymce

ttp://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/

config of tinymce :

`

```
        tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste filemanager"
                 ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
        });
    </script>`
```

config of filemanager :

`$base_url="http://localhost";`

`$upload_dir = '/images/uploaded';`

`$current_path = '../../../../../images/uploaded';`

I don't have browse button in Edit/Upload image popup window as it is on tinymce site .
See on the pictures, please help.

http://s29.postimg.org/5mwg8p4mv/tinymy.png  <-my
http://s29.postimg.org/o7p9tifg7/tinymce.png   <- tinymce sample on site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the below line in your tinyMCE editor code...

file_browser_callback :true

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable filebrowser for the button to show up. This is described here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:file_browser_callback